# Extracting currency from string

Tags: swift2, substring, currency

This is Swift 2.1.

How would you go about extracting an amount from a string that looks like "add egg (£2.00)"? In this example, I would need the "2.00" portion.

Would it be a hard-check looking for whatever's enclosed between the brackets? Or is there a more effective way to do so? I.e. regex or something?

Comment: Your string "add egg (£2.00)" should always in this pattern ?

I mean, "add <your_Item_name> (£<Item_Qty>)"

Comment: For now, yes. But I'd like to keep things more dynamic in case the pattern needs to change in the future, thus thinking along the lines of regex.

Comment: for regex, you need a fix patten to match.

Comment: isn't currency a pattern already (i.e. £2.00)? Or do you mean that it needs to be at a specific position within the string? Regex shouldn't care about fixed positions, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's many ways to achieve what you want - here's a simple example with a regex.

I'm using `(?<=\\()[^\\)]+` to find anything between `(` and `)`, then I use a couple of ranges to extract the values: one for the currency symbol, another for the value.

```
extension String {
    func extractValueBetweenParenthesis() -> (currency: String?, value: String?) {
        if let range = self.rangeOfString("(?<=\\()[^\\)]+", options: .RegularExpressionSearch) {
            let cr = range.startIndex..<range.startIndex.advancedBy(1)
            let vr = range.startIndex.advancedBy(1)..<range.endIndex
            return (currency: self.substringWithRange(cr), value: self.substringWithRange(vr))
        }
        return (nil, nil)
    }
}
```

Call the method on a String then safely unwrap the optional results:

```
let str = "add egg (£2.00)"
let result = str.extractValueBetweenParenthesis()
if let currency = result.currency, value = result.value {
    print("Currency is '\(currency)' and value is '\(value)'")
}
```

Prints:

> Currency is '£' and value is '2.00'

Answer (score 1):

'pure' Swift solution, no brackets necessary

```
let str = ["add egg £ 2.00",
           "the price is $12.00 per unit",
           "send €10.22 to somebody",
           "invalid $(12)"]

func value(str: String, currency: String)->Double {
    var chars = str.characters
    let currs = currency.characters

    while !currs.contains(chars.popFirst() ?? " ") {}

    let arr = chars.split(" ")
    guard let value = arr.first,
        let d  = Double(String(value)) else { return Double.NaN }
    return d
}

let values = str.flatMap { value($0, currency: "£$€") }
print(values)
/*
 [2.0, 12.0, 10.220000000000001, nan]
 */
```

if you really need the brackets there, no problem ...

```
let str = ["add egg (£2.00)",
           "the price is ($12.00) per unit",
           "send (€10.22) to somebody",
           "invalid ($-12)"]

func value(str: String, currency: String)->Double {
    var chars = str.characters
    let currs = currency.characters

    while !currs.contains(chars.popFirst() ?? " ") {}

    let arr = chars.split(")")
    guard let value = arr.first,
        let d  = Double(String(value)) else { return Double.NaN }
    return d
}

let values = str.flatMap { value($0, currency: "£$€") }
print(values)
/*
 [2.0, 12.0, 10.220000000000001, -12.0]
 */
```

Comment: thank you this is great but I've accepted the reggex answer since it's closer to my requirements

Answer (score -1):

```
var myString = "add egg (£2.00)"
myString = myString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("", withString: "")
let components = myString.componentsSeparatedByString("add egg (£")
let finalString = components[1].stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(")", withString: "")
print(finalString)
```

//This prints 2.00

Comment: why down voted , it's working, what's wrong with it when you tested it?

Comment: that wasn't me :) Will give it a try tonight.